# problem with get_absolute_url django python

Tags: python, django

I used get_absolute_url in my app but it works only on admin site (by button view on site). On my website, the hyperlink is not responding. I've checked every line of code a couple of times and it seems like everything's fine. Does anyone know why it doesn't works?

models.py

```
class CrashReport(models.Model):
    number_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    date_notice = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)

    SHIFT_NUMBER = (
        ('I', 'Zmiana I (6:00 - 14:00)'),
        ('II', 'Zmiana II (14:00 - 22:00)'),
        ('III', 'Zmiana III (22:00 - 06:00)'),

    )

    which_shift = models.CharField(
        max_length=3,
        choices=SHIFT_NUMBER,
        blank=True,
        default='I',
        help_text='Zmiana.'
    )

    who_notice = models.ManyToManyField(Author, help_text='Select a occupation for this employee')
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000, help_text='Please type what happened')
    which_stuff = models.ManyToManyField(Device, help_text='Select a exactly devices')

    PROCESSING_STATUS = (
        ('o', 'Otwarty'),
        ('p', 'Przetwarzanie'),
        ('z', 'Zakonczony'),
    )

    status_notice = models.CharField(
        max_length=1,
        choices=PROCESSING_STATUS,
        blank=True,
        default='o',
        help_text='Status dokumentu.'
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return f'ZGL /{self.number_id} / {self.which_stuff.all()} / {self.date_notice}'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('crashreport-detail', args=[str(self.number_id)])
```

views.py

from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.views import generic
    from .models import CrashReport

```
def index(request):
    """View function for home page of site."""

    # Generate counts of some of the main objects
    num_crashreports = CrashReport.objects.all().count()
    # num_instances = BookInstance.objects.all().count()

    # Opens Crashreports (status = 'o')
  #  num_crashreport_open = CrashReport.objects.filter(status__exact='o').count()

    context = {
        'num_crashreports': num_crashreports,
     #   'num_crashreports_processing': num_crashreports_processing,
     #   'num_crashreports_open': num_crashreports_open,
    }

    # Render the HTML template index.html with the data in the context variable
    return render(request, 'dokumenty/index.html', context=context)


class CrashReportsListView(generic.ListView):
    model = CrashReport
    context_object_name = 'crash_reports_list'   # your own name for the list as a template variable
    queryset = CrashReport.objects.filter()[:5] # Get 5 crash reports

class CrashReportsDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = CrashReport
```

urls.py

from django.urls import path, reverse

```
        from . import views

        urlpatterns = [
            path('', views.index, name='index'),
            path('crashreports/', views.CrashReportsListView.as_view(), name='crashreports'),
            path('crashreport/<int:pk>', views.CrashReportsDetailView.as_view(), name='crashreport-detail'),
```

crashreport_list.html

```
{% extends 'baza.html' %}
{% block content %}

<h>Witam w Systemie Ewidencji Maria Awaria Service - Raporty</h>


  <h1>Zgłoszenia</h1>
  {% if crash_reports_list %}
  <ul>
    {% for crashreports in crash_reports_list %}
    <li>
        <a href="{{ crashreport.get_absolute_url }}">ZGL /{{ crashreports.number_id }} / {{ crashreports.which_stuff.all|join:", " }} / {{crashreports.date_notice}}</a>,

    </li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
  {% else %}
    <p>There are no crash reports in the system.</p>
  {% endif %}



{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
<a href="{{ crashreports.get_absolute_url }}">....</a>
```

not `href="{{ crashreport.get_absolute_url }}"` because you are using `crashreports` when iterating in for loop:

```
{% for crashreports in crash_reports_list %}
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```